# Dynamics AX - Adding tables to DatabaseLog programatically in AX 2009

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

I'm looking for a way to enable logging changes for certain tables. 
I have tried and tested adding tables to database log programatically, but with various success so far - sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't (mostly it does not) - it seems simply inserting rows into `DatabaseLog` table doesn't quite do the trick.

What I have tried:
Adding row with proper tableId, fieldId, logType and .
 Domain had been assigned as 'Admin', main company, empty field and subcompanies with the same result.
I have created class that handles inserts, main two functions are:

```c
public static void InsertBase(STR tableName, domainId _domain='Admin')
{
    //base logging for insert, delete, uptade on fieldid=0
    DatabaseLog DBDict;
    TableId _tableId;
    DatabaseLogType _logType;
    fieldId _fieldId =0;
    List logTypes;
    int i;
    ListEnumerator enumerator;
    ;

    _tableId= tableName2id(tableName);

    logTypes = new List(Types::Enum);

    logTypes.addEnd(DatabaseLogType::Insert);
    logTypes.addEnd(DatabaseLogType::Update);
    logTypes.addEnd(DatabaseLogType::Delete);
    logTypes.addEnd(DatabaseLogType::EventInsert);
    logTypes.addEnd(DatabaseLogType::EventUpdate);
    logTypes.addEnd(DatabaseLogType::EventDelete);

    enumerator = logTypes.getEnumerator();
    while(enumerator.moveNext())
    {
        _logType = enumerator.current();

        select * from dbdict where
                dbdict.logTable==_tableId && dbdict.logField==_fieldId
                && dbdict.logType==_logType;
        if(!dbDict) //that means it doesnt exist
        {
            dbdict.logTable=_tableId;
            dbdict.logField=_fieldId;
            dbdict.logType=_logType;
            dbdict.domainId=_domain;
            dbdict.insert();
        }
    }
    info("Success");
}
```

and the method that lists every single field and adds as logType::Update

```c
public static void init(str TableName, DomainId domain='Admin')
{
    DatabaseLogType logtype;
    int i;
    container kk, ll;
    DatabaseLog dblog;
    tableid _tableId;
    fieldid _fieldid;
    ;

    logtype = DatabaseLogType::Update;
    //holds a container of not yet added table fields to databaselog
    kk = BLX_AddTableToDatabaseLog::buildFieldList(logtype,TableName);
    for(i=1; i <= conlen(kk);i++)
    {
        ll = conpeek(kk,i);
        _tableid = tableName2id(tableName);
        _fieldid = conpeek(ll,1);
        info(strfmt("%1 %2", conpeek(ll,1),conpeek(ll,2)));

        dblog.logType=logType;
        dblog.logTable = _tableId;
        dblog.domainId = domain;
        dblog.logField =_fieldid;
        dblog.insert();
    }
}
```

result: 
[image: Select * from databaselog where logtable=662]

What am I missing ?

@EDIT with some additional info
Does not work for `SalesTable` and `SalesLine`, `WMSBillOfLading`. 
I couldn't add log for `SalesTable` and `SalesLine` by using wizard in administration panel, but my colleague somehow did (she has done exactly the same  things as me). We also tried to add log to various other tables and we often found out that she could while I could not and vice versa (and sometimes none managed to do it like in case of `WMSBillOfLading` table). 
The inconsistency of this mechanism is what drove me to write this code, which I hoped would solve all the problems.

Comment: Looks good at first glance. I did something similar in AX 2012 and it worked quite well. Could you check if `SysDatabaseLogWizard::tableAllowed(tableId)` is available in AX 2009, that is one difference I can spot between your code and mine. Other than that, maybe [edit] some additional information into your question for which tables it works and for which it does not?

Comment: SysDatabaseLogWizard::tableAllowed(662)) returns true.
Maybe AOS restart is necessary for it to work? I have not tested that yet.
And table it worked for was InventDimCombination, that's the only example I know for sure that went successful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After doing your setup changes you probably have to call

```
SysFlushDatabaseLogSetup::main();
```

in order to flush any caches.
This method is also called in the standard AX code in the form method  `SysDatabaseLogTableSetup\Methods\close` and in the class method `SysDatabaseLogWizard\doRun`.

Comment: Good idea. This should be done for all values of `dataAreaId`.

Comment: Seems like that's it, worked like a charm. 
You also have to call this method on every AOS instance you have installed. 
It didn't work for InventDim though, but I didn't finish tinkering with it yet (it's possible I've done sth wrong). 
I don't want to accept answer too soon (since it didn't work for InventDim), so I'll wait till tommorrow when i'm done testing and aos'es are restarted.